# Roman and arabic numbering in combine environment?

Tags: table-of-contents, combine

I'm putting together an academic journal for my student history society and am wondering whether I can have different papers in the combine environment display as roman or arabic numbers. The editorial introduction would preferably be in roman numerals, and the rest of the papers in arabic.

Right now, this is what the code looks like, less some of the unnecessary stuff like blockquote environments, actual titles, etc.:

```
%Preamble
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{combine}

% 6.5x9.5in, 1in margin
\usepackage{geometry}                       
\geometry{paperheight=9.5in,paperwidth=6.5in,margin=1in}          

\usepackage{graphicx}               

\usepackage{amssymb}

% Header/Footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{palatino}

%Date
\date{}


%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

%title info
\title{\Huge \emph{The Title}\\
\Large Volume 1, Issue 1 (Winter 2015)}
\author{}

%title page
\maketitle
\fancyhf{}
\thispagestyle{empty}

%Publishing info page
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\fancyhf{}

{\footnotesize
\noindent

Yadda yadda ISSN}

% Table of contents
\newpage
{\small
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
}

%empty page
\newpage
\fancyhf{}
\thispagestyle{empty}

%%%%%%

\begin{papers}

\coltoctitle{Introduction} 
\coltocauthor{The Dude, Editor-in-Chief} 
\label{Introduction}
\import{intro}
% I'd like this in roman numerals - paper as well as toc entry

\coltoctitle{Title One} 
\coltocauthor{Author One} 
\label{TitleOne}
\import{TitleOne}
% And then this one and the following as arabic numbers

\coltoctitle{Title Two} 
\coltocauthor{Author Two} 
\label{TitleTwo}
\import{TitleTwo}

\end{papers}

%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

How do? I can't seem to figure this one out. I would rather not have to use the section command and have big "EDITORIAL" and "ARTICLES" section headers in the toc with numbers in front of them like a STEM journal. I'm a humanities student and this is my first LaTeX project so forgive me if this is a simple answer.

Comment: Here is a useful discussion on combine:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197266/multiple-documents-by-different-authors-and-one-table-of-contents/197542#197542

Comment: Thanks for this. I've got a working toc, though. I'm just wondering about the numerals.